# When does E[XY] = XE[Y] hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I am wondering, when does

$$ \mathbb{E}[XY] = X\mathbb{E}[Y] $$

hold for two random Variables $X$ and $Y$?

**Idea:** If $XY$ is independent of a sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ we have $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[XY|\mathcal{F}]$. And now we have $ \mathbb{E}[XY] = X\mathbb{E}[Y] $ if $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Is that correct? Can this property be described in a different way?

Comment: There's something a little weird here in that $\mathbb{E}[\text{anything}]$ will be a real number but $X$ is a random variable (which might be more than that)? I don't know; I'm not a probabilist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[XY|\sigma(\emptyset)]$, that is - the Sigma algebra generated by the empty set, i.e $\{\Omega,\emptyset\}$, known also as the trivial sigma-algebra. Then it will follows that $\mathbb{E}[XY] = X\mathbb{E}[Y]$ if and only if $X$ is measurable with respect to the trivial sigma-algebra, which in turn means $X$ is in fact constant.

Comment: The one annoying counterexample is $Y=0$ a.s. (in which case the RHS is degenerate even if $X$ is not degenerate).

Comment: Thank you, that completely makes sense!

Comment: Sorry, there are other annoying counterexamples when $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ is also zero.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote can only hold if $X$ is a constant, since the LHS is a constant, and the RHS is a random variable.

Did you mean to write $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y]$?